# No module named 'socketio' when from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

Tags: sockets, flask, python-3.7

I am developing a project in Python 3.7 that uses flask-sockeio but when I try to import:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
```

i receive this error:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
  File "C:\Users\G.Ventura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import socketio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socketio
```

Someone use flask-sockeio on python3 ?
thanks

Comment: does your script name is `flask_socketio` or `socketio` by chance? and please add full import with post.